# Why does Interface Builder constantly update its files (changes seem arbitrary)?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xib, nib

Everyday, I notice in Xcode 4.5 with source control, Interface Builder very frequently changes xib files.

For example, I could open a xib and click on one of the views on the left side and switch one of the inspectors on the right.  And without actually doing any work, or modifying the file, the file is marked as unsaved.  Okay so I save it.

Then the Version assistant editor will show changes that seem arbitrary, sometimes even destructive.  In example: today I saw a long list of outlets that disappeared from the file, and a minute later they were back in the file, without me changing anything.

This seems a bit frustrating because it can lead to useless commits that have no useful changes.  I've reverted some times, and other times committed with a message like "automatic system-generated changes to xib file".
Including automatic changes in commits could lead to confusion when reviewing historical changes.  Genuine changes to a xib like creating a new object or changing the class name or autoresizing mask may get lost in the sea of unnecessary changes.

---

This is a duplicate of another SO question: [How to disable Interface Builder document versioning from auto updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654796/how-to-disable-interface-builder-document-versioning-from-auto-updating?rq=1)

This issue was filed on radar by calvinBhai, that was later marked as a dupe of Bug ID# 11533872